# wpf. Easy way to hide tile brush overflow

Tags: wpf, drawingbrush

I use DrawingBrush to show drag marker - dotted line.

```
<Rectangle Height="19" Width="7">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile"
                      Viewbox="0,0,2,2"
                      Viewport="0,0,4,4"
                      ViewportUnits="Absolute"
                      ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF6D6D6D">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            <EllipseGeometry Center="1,1"
                                             RadiusX="1"
                                             RadiusY="1" />
                        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Problem - cannot use it with `Height=auto`, dot-tiles may be sliced:

[image]

Is there an easy way to hide incomplete tiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve the desired result by a simple custom FrameworkElement, which only draws full circles that fit into the element's width and height:

```
public class DragMarker : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundProperty =
        Control.ForegroundProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DragMarker));

    public Brush Foreground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ForegroundProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < (int)ActualHeight / 4; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (int)ActualWidth / 4; x++)
            {
                drawingContext.DrawEllipse(Foreground, null,
                    new Point(x * 4 + 2, y * 4 + 2), 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```